# How do I specify `weak` self in curried function

Tags: swift, closures

I have a `UIViewController` which calls an async function on one of its properties. For the callback, instead of a closure I would like to provide a function which has the right parameter types.

```
class Fetcher {
    func fetch(completion: ([String] -> ())) {
        // ... do stuff
        completion([ ... ])
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let fetcher = Fetcher()

    func fetch() {
        fetcher.fetch(didFetch)
    }

    func didFetch(result: [String]) {
         // handle result
    }
}
```

Every thing works fine, except there is a retain cycle between the two objects that would have been fixed if I had done:

```
fetcher.fetch() { [weak self] in
     // handle result
}
```

Is there a way to cancel the retain cycle in the initial setup?

---

**EDIT**

Something I missed: `Fetcher.fetch` does not specify how the retain cycle will happen (for e.g., it may retain the closure strongly), but that was my intention, by not having it be marked `@noescape`. Apologies!

Comment: Perhaps you could remove the reference to "curried function"s in you title as there is no mention of them in the question?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think there is a retain cycle? `Fetcher` is not storing the passed in `completion` reference. If you run the following in a playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class Fetcher {
    
    func fetch(completion: [String] -> ()) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("fetching")
            completion([])
        }
    }
    
    deinit { print("deinit Fetcher") }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let fetcher = Fetcher()
    
    func fetch() {
        fetcher.fetch(didFetch)
    }
    
    func didFetch(result: [String]) {
        print("did fetch")
    }
    
    deinit { print("deinit ViewController") }
}

var vc: ViewController? = ViewController()
vc?.fetch()
vc = nil
```

... you'll see everything prints as it should:

```
fetching
did fetch
deinit ViewController
deinit Fetcher
```

However, were you to store the reference for some reason:

```
class Fetcher {
    
    var completion: ([String] -> ())? 
    
    func fetch(completion: [String] -> ()) {
        self.completion = completion // causing retain cycle
        completion([])
    }
}
```

Then you would indeed have a retain cycle and the two objects would never `deinit`...

## Edit

This question is growing on me. In particular, since `@noescape` is currently impossible to enforce as we pass into asynchronous execution, how close can we get to such an ideal? There are two approaches that come to mind, neither of which unfortunately offers compiler backed guarantees to the caller, though they are still in the spirit of the original question in the sense that they do not involve passing in a closure:

```
protocol CompletionHandler : AnyObject { // only needed for `fetch2`
    associatedtype Result
    func onCompletion(_: Result)
}

extension Fetcher {
    
    func fetch2 <H: CompletionHandler where H.Result == [String]> (handler: H) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak handler] in
            print("fetching2")
            handler?.onCompletion([])
        }
    }
    
    func fetch3 <T: AnyObject> (handler: T, curry: T -> [String] -> ()) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak handler] in
            print("fetching3")
            if let handler = handler {
                curry(handler)([])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... which can be used like so (where `fetch2` assumes conformance to `CompletionHandler`):

```
fetcher.fetch2(self)
fetcher.fetch3(self, curry: ViewController.onCompletion)
```

... with the effect of:

```
var vc: ViewController? = ViewController()
vc?.fetch()
vc = nil
```

... printing:

```
deinit ViewController
deinit Fetcher
fetching2
fetching3
```

(compare to the console output of the first solution above and see the discussion with @Sulthan in the comments below)

Comment: You example is invalid because you are not actually using any asynchronous calls there.

Comment: "Invalid" is perhaps a little too strong, but you are right that the asynchrony is at the heart of the question even if not present in @raheel's code example. I've edited my playground example accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: You are right that the retain cycle is only temporary, however, the problem is that while `fetch` is running asynchronously, `ViewController` is not released.

Comment: That is correct, but it is also a grey area in terms of desired behaviour. Calling `fetch` with a closure whilst capturing `self` weakly would indeed allow immediate releasing of the two objects, but the fetching itself would proceed until finished. If this is of real concern for a particular app, then it would require a more careful design, e.g. using `NSOperation` and canceling?

Comment: @Sulthan: "because you are not actually using any asynchronous calls there" Neither does the question. The question only shows a *synchronous* call.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not specify the retain cycle explicitly in the `Fetcher.fetch` method, but that was the intention: `Fetcher` would/could hold on to the passed closure, since it was not marked `@noescape`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a method to a closure parameter, then `self` will have to be captured, there is no way around that.

However, you can be more explicit and wrap the method call in a new closure:

```
func fetch() {
   fetcher.fetch { [weak self] in
       self?.didFetch($0)
   }        
}
```

Comment: Whilst this is the right way to go in many common scenarios, it is a general point of recommendation rather than an answer to the question as posed: "Is there a way to cancel the retain cycle in the initial setup?"